# Push values to Array of a Model

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing some issues while trying to populate an array of a model I created in order to send it to my Service Component.

Here I declared my array:

```
  itemsCopied: Array<InventoryTransactionFullModel> = [];
```

And in the submit method where I try to populate the array and get the error is this

```
  this.itemsCopied.push({
  productWarehouseId: this.form.warehouseId.value,
  productStorageTypeId: this.form.storageTypeId.value,
  documentNumber: this.form.documentNumber.value,
  transactionDate: this.form.expenseDate.value,
  pSLId: this.form.productServiceLineId.value,
  description: this.form.description.value,
  totalAmount: this.form.totalAmount.value, 
  exchangeRate: this.form.defaultExchangeRate.value,
})
```

The error I get is the following:

[image]

What is the right way to populate this array?

Comment: It seems that you're trying to push an element which is not of type `InventoryTransactionFullModel`. You need to make sure that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that the type `InventoryTransactionFullModel` has a lot more required properties than the object you are currently trying to push to the array. So you can either add these properties (like `id`, `currencyId`, `taxes` and the other 16).

Other option is to mark these properties as optional by adding a `?` behind them in the type declaration:

```
type InventoryTransactionFullModel = {
  productWarehouseId;
  productStorageTypeId;
  documentNumber;
  transactionDate;
  pSLId;
  description;
  totalAmount;
  exchangeRate;
  id?;
  currencyId?;
  taxes?;
  //etc.
}
```